# How to parse amazon's rds instances information using jq with streams?

Tags: jq

While trying to parse [Amazon's RDS instances](https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonRDS/current/index.json) to mount an object of instanceType=memoryInBytes I used almost 1GB of memory so I tried to use jq with --stream to try and make it a bit better but, I can only output the key and the value on the next line.

On my current try, this is the used jq expression I've created:

**Note** that `(. | tostream)` is used only because the playground does not support the `--stream` flag.

```
def isMemory: .[0][3] == "memory";
def isInstanceType: .[0][3] == "instanceType";

(. | tostream) | select(isMemory or isInstanceType) | .[1]
```

Which then outputs

```
"db.r5.24xlarge"
"768 GiB"
"db.r4.large"
"15.25 GiB"
```

When running with a smaller version of that json:

```
{
  "formatVersion" : "v1.0",
  "disclaimer" : "This pricing list is for informational purposes only. All prices are subject to the additional terms included in the pricing pages on http://aws.amazon.com. All Free Tier prices are also subject to the terms included at https://aws.amazon.com/free/",
  "offerCode" : "AmazonRDS",
  "version" : "20230328234721",
  "publicationDate" : "2023-03-28T23:47:21Z",
  "products" : {
    "BHYABS232JP4AGQY" : {
      "sku" : "BHYABS232JP4AGQY",
      "productFamily" : "Database Instance",
      "attributes" : {
        "servicecode" : "AmazonRDS",
        "location" : "US East (Ohio)",
        "locationType" : "AWS Region",
        "instanceType" : "db.r5.24xlarge",
        "currentGeneration" : "Yes",
        "instanceFamily" : "Memory optimized",
        "vcpu" : "96",
        "physicalProcessor" : "Intel Xeon Platinum 8175",
        "clockSpeed" : "Up to 3.1 GHz",
        "memory" : "768 GiB",
        "storage" : "EBS Only",
        "networkPerformance" : "25 Gigabit",
        "processorArchitecture" : "64-bit",
        "engineCode" : "18",
        "databaseEngine" : "MariaDB",
        "licenseModel" : "No license required",
        "deploymentOption" : "Single-AZ",
        "usagetype" : "USE2-InstanceUsage:db.r5.24xl",
        "operation" : "CreateDBInstance:0018",
        "dedicatedEbsThroughput" : "14000 Mbps",
        "enhancedNetworkingSupported" : "Yes",
        "instanceTypeFamily" : "R5",
        "normalizationSizeFactor" : "192",
        "regionCode" : "us-east-2",
        "servicename" : "Amazon Relational Database Service"
      }
    },
    "D8GBHQEK73G5ADCK" : {
      "sku" : "D8GBHQEK73G5ADCK",
      "productFamily" : "Database Instance",
      "attributes" : {
        "servicecode" : "AmazonRDS",
        "location" : "Asia Pacific (Tokyo)",
        "locationType" : "AWS Region",
        "instanceType" : "db.r4.large",
        "currentGeneration" : "No",
        "instanceFamily" : "Memory optimized",
        "vcpu" : "2",
        "physicalProcessor" : "Intel Xeon E5-2686 v4 (Broadwell)",
        "clockSpeed" : "2.3 GHz",
        "memory" : "15.25 GiB",
        "storage" : "EBS Only",
        "networkPerformance" : "Up to 10 Gigabit",
        "processorArchitecture" : "64-bit",
        "engineCode" : "2",
        "databaseEngine" : "MySQL",
        "licenseModel" : "No license required",
        "deploymentOption" : "Multi-AZ",
        "usagetype" : "APN1-Multi-AZUsage:db.r4.large",
        "operation" : "CreateDBInstance:0002",
        "dedicatedEbsThroughput" : "400 Mbps",
        "enhancedNetworkingSupported" : "Yes",
        "instanceTypeFamily" : "R4",
        "normalizationSizeFactor" : "8",
        "processorFeatures" : "Intel AVX, Intel AVX2, Intel Turbo",
        "regionCode" : "ap-northeast-1",
        "servicename" : "Amazon Relational Database Service"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also get the [playground link to try it.](https://jqplay.org/s/B7e4h3FUALA).

The initial expresion I had, which would then use too much memory was the following:

```
.products | to_entries | map(.value.attributes | select(.instanceType != null) | {(.instanceType): ((.memory | split(" ") | .[0] | tonumber) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)}) | add
```

it works but it will blow the memory every time I run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implentation using `tostream` also loads the whole input, and just then breaks it down into its streamed format. Instead, use the `--stream` flag to read in the input in streamed format right away.

Here's one approach loading only the `.attributes` objects in full into memory. Using `reduce` lets you iteratively build up your final object.

```bash
jq --stream -n '
  reduce fromstream(3|truncate_stream(
    inputs | select(.[0][2] == "attributes")
  )) as {$instanceType, $memory} ({};
    if $instanceType then .[$instanceType] = $memory else . end
  )
'
```

```json
{
  "db.r5.24xlarge": "768 GiB",
  "db.r4.large": "15.25 GiB"
}
```

Comment: That tostream is because the playground does not accept `--stream`, it is only way to show as an example. But whenever you see tostream, imagine it came with `--stream` on the command line

Comment: @JaysonReis You didn't explicate that in your question, and it *does* make a difference in performance. -- Is your desired output the one you are showing (but using `--stream` isn't performing well enough) or the one your "initial expresion" was producing (and you are asking how to produce that using `--stream`)?

Comment: the current one was this `curl -s https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonRDS/current/index.json | jq  '.products | to_entries | map(.value.attributes | select(.instanceType != null) | {(.instanceType): ((.memory | split(" ") | .[0] | tonumber) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)}) | add'`  and while trying with `--stream` I can filter, the key and the value but, if using `fromstream` and `truncate_stream`, the output is blank because i filter out the path-leaf

Comment: I think that is more relevant to your question, you should edit it in. Also, I update my answer with how I would do it using `--stream` and `reduce`.

Comment: Tests with your original input file (~200 MB) produced an object with 193 entries. The processing took ~20s and used <100 MB RAM.

Comment: ~200MB on your code or mine?
```
cat index.json | time jq '.products | to_entries | map(.value.attributes | select(.instanceType != null) | {(.instanceType): ((.memory | split(" ") | .[0] | tonumber) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)}) | add' > /dev/null
8.93user 0.96system 0:13.83elapsed 71%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 891564maxresident)k
72inputs+0outputs (3major+381582minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

on my it is roughtly ~800MiB

and yours 3,30 MiB
on next comment

Comment: ```
 cat index.json | time jq --stream -n '
  reduce fromstream(3|truncate_stream(
    inputs | select(.[0][2] == "attributes")
  )) as {$instanceType, $memory} ({};
    if $instanceType then .[$instanceType] = $memory else . end
  )
' > /dev/null
35.66user 0.25system 0:39.47elapsed 90%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3372maxresident)k
144inputs+0outputs (4major+496minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```